# Is it better for an API to dispatch itself to a queue and invoke a callback, or for the API caller to do the dispatching?

Tags: ios, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

### Examples:

Asynchronous method with its own dispatching:

```
// Library
func asyncAPI(callback: Result -> Void) {
  dispatch_async(self.queue) {
    ...
    callback(result)
  }
}

// Caller
asyncAPI() { result in
  ...
}
```

Synchronous method with exposed dispatch queue:

```
// Library
func syncAPI() -> Result {
  assert(isRunningOnCorrectQueue())
  ...
  return result
}

// Caller
dispatch_async(api.queue) {
  let result = api.syncAPI()
  ...
}
```

These two examples behave the same but I am looking to learn whether one of these ends up complicating a larget codebase more than the other, especially when there is a lot of asynchrony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue against *both* of the patterns you propose.

For the first pattern (where the API manages it's own backgrounding) I see little or no benefit to doing it this way, as opposed to leaving it to the caller. If you want to use a private, serial queue to protect data (or any other sort of critical section) internal to your API, that's fine, but that queue should be private, and it should specifically not target any public, non-global-concurrent queue (Note: it should *especially* not target the main queue). Ideally, the primary implementation of your API would also take a second parameter, so callers can specify on which queue to invoke the callback. (People can work around the lack of such a parameter by passing a callback block that re-dispatches to their desired queue, but I think that's clunkier than having an extra, optional parameter.) This puts the API consumer in complete control of the concurrency, while preserving your freedom to use queues internally to protect state.

As to the second approach, it's my opinion that we all should avoid creating new synchronous, *blocking* API. When you provide a synchronous, blocking API and don't provide a callback-based version, that means that you have denied consumers of your API any opportunity to avoid blocking. When you only provide synchronous, blocking API, then if someone wants to call your API in the background, at least one thread (in addition to any additional threads that your API consumes behind the scenes) will be consumed from the finite number of threads available to each process. (In the worst case this can lead to starvation conditions that are effectively deadlocks.)

Another red flag with this second example is that it vends a queue; Any time an API *vends* a queue, something is amiss. As mentioned, if you want to use a private serial queue to protect state or other critical sections internal to your API, go for it, but don't expose that queue to the outside world. If nothing else, it unnecessarily exposes details of your implementation. In looking at the system framework headers, I couldn't find a single case where a `dispatch_queue_t` was vended where it wasn't immediately obvious that the intent was for the API consumer to push *in* the queue, and not read it *out*.

It's also worth mentioning that these patterns are problematic regardless of whether your workload is CPU-bound or IO-bound. If it's CPU-bound, then not managing your own dispatch gives consumers of the API explicit control over how this CPU work is executed. If your workload is IO-bound, then you should use the OS- and libdispatch-provided asynchronous IO mechanisms (`dispatch_io`, `dispatch_sources`, `kevent`, etc) to avoid consuming a thread (or more than one) for the duration of your work.

Another answer here implied that forcing consumers to manage their own concurrency leads to "boilerplate" code. If you feel that the burden of API consumers potentially having to wrap calls to your API with `dispatch_async` is too great, then feel free to provide a convenience overload that dispatches to the default global concurrent queue, but please always leave the version that allows API consumers the ability to explicitly manage their own concurrency.

If, on the other hand, all this is internal to the implementation, and not part of the public API, then do whatever is most expedient, knowing that you can refactor the implementation behind the public API any time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the 2 generally accomplish the same thing but the first is more preferable in most scenarios. There are several benefits to using the first method.

1. The API is simpler. You simply call the method and provide code for the callback block.
2. Less boilerplate code, No typing `dispatch_async` every time you want to call it as it is just included in the method itself.
3. Less room for bugs/errors. By wrapping the asynchronous logic inside the method itself, you ensure that it is called on the right queue internally without the caller having to worry about any of that.
4. Touching on the last point, you also have finer control over the queue itself. Let's say you are trying to perform certain tasks on a particular queue. It is way simpler to simply wrap the code in a GCD call on that queue a single time rather than having to remember to reuse that same queue every time you want to call the method.